# errors when building zepto

Tags: zepto

when I try to build zepto I get the following error:

```
MODULES="zepto event polyfill detect fx fx_methods ajax form selector touch gesture" ./make dist
Error: Cannot find module 'shelljs/make'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kevin/etcgit/zepto/make:4:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kevin/etcgit/zepto/make:153:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.exports.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:124:25)
    at compileScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:166:29)
    at fs.stat.notSources.(anonymous function) (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:141:18)
    at fs.readFile (fs.js:176:14)
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
```

not sure whats going on... I did install shell js but that didnt get rid of the error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you run `npm install` first. So...

```
cd src/js/libs/zepto
npm install
MODULES="zepto event polyfill detect fx fx_methods ajax form selector touch gesture" ./make dist
```

From https://github.com/madrobby/zepto#building

I ran into the same problem myself...

Good luck,
Rob.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to custom package,please open the file 'make' in the zepto root directoy and find the line 42.Then you will see:

```
modules = (env['MODULES'] || 'zepto event ajax form ie touch').split(' ')
```

Modify the package that split with space, after save it. Run the

```
npm run-script dist
```

In previous,you must have installed all the packages that depended on.